# Python 7z Pyunpack TypeError

Tags: python, compression, typeerror, 7zip

I'm having some trouble with Pyunpack.

The variable `thing` is the path to the 7z file.

```
from pyunpack import Archive
Archive(thing).extractall(str(thing[0:thing.rfind('/')]))
```

This code is intended to extract the 7z file to its directory.

In this case, `thing` is a relative path:
`./relative/path/my_7z_file.7z`

This returns a vague TypeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "importItAll.py", line 33, in <module>
    Archive(thing).extractall(str(thing[0:thing.rfind('/')]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyunpack/__init__.py", line 74, in extractall
    self.extractall_patool(directory, patool_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyunpack/__init__.py", line 41, in extractall_patool
    '--outdir=' + directory,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/easyprocess/__init__.py", line 108, in __init__
self.cmd_as_string = ' '.join(self.cmd)  # TODO: not perfect
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string, NoneType found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at the code for [pyunpack.Archive](https://github.com/ponty/pyunpack/blob/master/pyunpack/__init__.py#L32) code. It would appear you are missing the [patool](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/patool) dependency of the library. This appears to be a bug within pyunpack where it will return a None for the function, instead of giving a usable error message:

`def _exepath(cmd):
    for p in os.environ['PATH'].split(os.pathsep):
        fullp = os.path.join(p, cmd)
        if os.access(fullp, os.X_OK):
            return fullp`

Which is default behavior for any function within python that doesn't have a return. Installing the patool dependency with `pip install patool` or `easy_install patool`, should resolve the issue.

Comment: I installed patool and my code now runs perfectly. Thank you!